Symmetric hyperbolic 3-manifold
Suppose one has a complete closed hyperbolic 3-manifold upon which there is an anti-conformal involution (a symmetry). Can one represent the manifold as a quotient of $\mathbb{H}^3$ by some discrete subgroup $\Gamma\leq\mathrm{PSL}(2,\mathbb{C})$ generated by words of even length in reflections over the faces of a polyhedron in $\mathbb{H}^3$.
For example, if we start with a compact hyperbolic 3-manifold with boundary and suppose that the double along the boundaries is hyperbolic, then it comes equipped with such an involution. Can we find such a representation of it as described above?
My question arises from the two-dimensional case where this is true (R. J. Sibner, Am. J. Math. 1968): one can construct a hyperbolic polygon $P$ with one boundary on the real axis and reflect the polygon along this boundary to obtain a fundamental polygon for the surface. The side pairing transformations are the words $\sigma g_i$ where $\sigma$ is reflection along the real axis and $g_i$ is reflection in one of the sides of $P$. $\sigma$ induces the involution on the resulting surface.
